# Concatenate timestamp column with string column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to push data from Cassandra to Elasticsearch. Loaded dataframe from `cassandra`, but column named `timestamp` is in `Long` format, so I needed to change it to `timestamp` to be more "human readable", which I did with:

```
val cassDF2 = spark.createDataFrame(rawCass).withColumn("timestamp", ($"timestamp").cast(TimestampType))
```

Dataframe now looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|             eventID|           timestamp|       userID|           sessionID|            fullJson|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|event00001.withSa...| 2018-11-15 09:00...|2512988381908|  WITH_EVENTS_IMPORT|{"header": {"appI...|
|event00002.withSa...| 2018-11-15 09:00...|2512988381908|WITH_EVENTS_SESSI...|{"body": {}, "hea...|
|event00003.withPa...| 2018-11-15 09:00...|2006052984315|  WITH_EVENTS_IMPORT|{"header": {"appI...|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now, I need to concatenate 3 columns (`seesionID, userID and timestamp`) into a new one (`docID`) and push it to ES:

```
  // concatStrings function
  val concatStrings = udf((userID: String, timestamp: String, eventID: String) => {userID + timestamp + eventID})

  // create column docID
  val cassDF = cassDF2.withColumn("docID", concatStrings($"userID", $"timestamp", $"eventID"))
```

Getting error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: "timestamp" is not a numeric
>   column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.

I know `timestamp` is after calling `.cast` now an object and cannot be aggregated like before (when it was type `Long`), but how to extract it's value as a String or something what can be aggregated.

All I can get is to accomplish this while `timestamp` column is `Long`.

My final data frame should look like `cassDF2` but with new column `docID` which contains  `251929883819082018-12-09T12:25:25.904+0100event00001.withSa...` instead of `15147612000002512988381908event00001.withSa...` in `docID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a UDF.  You can use built-in method `concat` to piece together the columns including the string-formatted `timestamp` column with specific date-format, as shown below:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.sql.Timestamp

val df = Seq(
  ("1001", Timestamp.valueOf("2018-11-15 09:00:00"), "Event1"),
  ("1002", Timestamp.valueOf("2018-11-16 10:30:00"), "Event2")
).toDF("userID", "timestamp", "eventID")

val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

df.
  withColumn("docID", concat($"userID", date_format($"timestamp", dateFormat), $"eventID")).
  show(false)
// +------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
// |userID|timestamp          |eventID|docID                                 |
// +------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
// |1001  |2018-11-15 09:00:00|Event1 |10012018-11-15T09:00:00.000-0800Event1|
// |1002  |2018-11-16 10:30:00|Event2 |10022018-11-16T10:30:00.000-0800Event2|
// +------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: is there any reason that number of docs in Cassandra is not equal with number in ES after import, even the same number of documents is being processed with my script?

Comment: @Dejan Marić, rather than posting as a comment, I would suggest that you assemble a separate question with relevant tags (e.g. Cassandra/Elasticsearch) and a minimal set of data that can reproduce the said problem.